# Run python script stored in blob storage using azure automation runbook

Tags: python, azure, powershell, automation, runbook

I created a adls storage account and stored here a simple python script to print hello world.script - `test.py`.

Created an azure runbook in powershell to run this `test.py` from the adls storage.

Can you please help with the code to execute the python script.

I am getting errors.

> Import-Module: Line | 12 | Import-Module -Name Azure.Storage.Blob |
>
> ```
> 'Azure.Storage.Blob' was not loaded because no valid module file was
> found in any module directory.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

To run python script in Azure Automation, you need to create a Python runbook as below(you cannot use azure powershell runbook for this):

[image]

Then add the required packages:

[image]

Blob in azure adls storage account:

[image]
Then use below code to get executed whats in the script:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

bsc = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=rithwik12344455;AccountKey=ZsxpsHf9VYOS+1TLyXMpk485z+ASt/5sklA==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net')
Cc = bsc.get_container_client('container name')
Bc = Cc.get_blob_client('blob name ')
text = Bc.download_blob().content_as_text()
text
exec(text)
```

Output:

[image]